# Visit a page using Javascript without leaving the current page

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file running on a page and I would like to log certain events as they occur. For example, I have a web store - and when people add an item to their cart, I want to log this event by visiting a page that I built:

```js
function log_event(id) {
  window.location.href = 'https://example.com/log/cart.php?id=' + id;
  return false;
}
```

The `log/cart.php` page doesn't really have anything to display, all it does is insert a record into a database containing the item that was added to the cart, and the date.

The code that calls this function looks like:

```js
document.getElementById('add-to-cart').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Add to the cart
  ...

  // Track the item that was added
  let id = document.getElementById('add-to-cart').getAttribute('data-id');
  log_event(id);
});
```

With my current code, the `log/cart.php` actually replaces the current page. I want the opening of `log/cart.php` to only happen in the background without the user being interrupted. I don't want it to actually open a browser tab or window and let the user stay in the product page.

Comment: You don\`t need to visit page. Just call native `fetch` request: `fetch(\`https://example.com/log/cart.php?id=${id}\`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an AJAX request to that endpoint:

```js
function log_event(id) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", 'https://example.com/log/cart.php?id=' + id, true);
  xhttp.send();
  return false;
}
```

[`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) can also be used, but be aware of its [browser support](https://caniuse.com/fetch) (no IE).

Comment: I am getting: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/' from origin 'https://mystore.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Not sure if that should be for another question or not.

Comment: @dokgu `https://example.com/` is not in the same domain as your site, hence the error.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? I believe it says `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be present on `https://example.com/` correct? How do I do that?

Comment: @dokgu Do you actually intend to send a request to `example.com`? It doesn't seem like that site serves much purpose for your needs. You should change it to the URL which you wish to send the request to.

Comment: On `cart.php` I added this line: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mystore.com');`. This works now, thanks!